# Allow custom function to take from lexical environment

Tags: lexical-scoping

I am trying to convert my code to use lexical binding.

I have a function (`format-template`) that calls a lambda function (let-bound to `replacer-inner`) from a user-customizable list (`template-replace-functions`) of functions based on a match-string. The replacer-inner function takes no arguments and returns a string, however, it *may* need to use variables `foo` `bar` and/or `baz`, which are passed as part of the argument `list` to `format-template`.

```
(setq lexical-binding t)

(defcustom template-replace-functions
  '(("email"
     (lambda () user-mail-address)
    ("apples"
     (lambda ()
       (cond ((= foo 1)
              "one")
             ((= foo 2)
              "two")
             ((= foo 3)
              "three")
             (t "four"))))
    ("bananas"
     (lambda ()
       (if (eq bar 'move)
           "movement" "sit still")))))
  "Association list of replacement functions.

For each STRING, the corresponding FUNCTION is called with no
arguments and must return a string."
  :type '(repeat (group string function))
  :group 'spice-girls)

(defun format-template (list)
  (let* ((foo (nth 0 list))
         (bar (nth 1 list))
         (baz (nth 2 list))
         template
         (replacer-outer
          (lambda ()
            (replace-regexp-in-string
             "\${\([^\s\t\n]*?\)}"
             (lambda (match)
               (let* ((key (match-string 1 match))
                      (replacer-inner
                       (cadr (assoc key template-replace-functions))))
                 (if (and replacer-inner
                          (stringp (funcall replacer-inner)))
                     (funcall replacer-inner) "")))
             template t t))))
    (setq template
          ...)
    (if template (funcall replacer-outer))))
```

So, for example, `list` contains three elements, which are let-bound to `foo` `bar` and `baz`. The `key` of the match-string is `"bananas"` which associates to a function in `template-replace-functions` and sets `replace-inner` to:

```
(lambda ()
       (if (eq bar 'move)
           "movement" "sit still"))
```

At this point, the above lambda function needs to know `bar`, which is fine using dynamic binding, but not so fine using lexical binding.

My question is, how do I do this to allow the lambda function bound to `replacer-inner` take from the let-bound values of `foo` `bar` and `baz`?

(Just to confuse things, the `replace-outer` function, which contains `replace-inner`, is let-bound because it is called from one of two places in the real function. I could have written inline here but have included it this way in case it adds to the problem.)

**Edit:**

Halfway there...

```
(setq lexical-binding t
  foo 0
  bar 0)

(setq inline-fun-1
      '(lambda ()
         (setq return
               (if (eq foo 1)
                   "Pass" "Fail"))))

(defmacro lex-fun ()
  `(let* ((foo 1)
          (bar 1)
          return)
     (funcall ,inline-fun-1)))

(lex-fun)    ; -> "Pass"

(defun inline-fun-2 ()
  (setq return
        (if (eq bar 1)
            "Pass" "Fail")))

(defmacro lex-fun ()
  `(let* ((foo 1)
          (bar 1)
          return)
     (funcall ,inline-fun-2)))

(lex-fun)    ; -> Lisp error: (void-variable inline-fun-2)
```

So, expanding the lambda function within a macro appears to work, but not a named function. But I do want to allow the user lambda or named functions. How to get around this?

Comment: BTW, formally speaking your `(lambda () user-mail-address)` is not a function.  Instead, it's a list of 3 elements, which happens to look the same as the source code for a function.  And Emacs is nice enough to turn one into the other if you pass that list to `funcall`.  But if you really want to say that it's a function, then you need to write `(("email" ,(lambda () user-mail-address) ...

Comment: @Stefan if the interpreter (Emacs) sees it as a function and the user sees it as a function, then pragmatically speaking, isn't it a function? Will Emacs ever not be nice enough to see it as a function?

Comment: @rnkn It's not a function to Emacs, it's just a list that happens to be converted implicitly in a few situations.  But there are notable differences: Lambda lists cannot close over surrounding bindings, and are never byte compiled.  They exist purely for historical reasons, not because they are a good idea.  You should not rely on this feature in today's Emacs Lisp code.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you cannot. This is why this kind of binding is called "lexical" - it prevents variables from escaping their definition area.

One way to address this problem: you could have passed some data-structure into the "bananas" function, where "bananas" would know how to extract values from it.  I.e.

```
(defcustom template-replace-functions
  '(("bananas" . (lambda (env) 
                   (let ((x (gethash "x" env "")))
                     (do-replacements-with x))))
    ...)))
```

Which assumes that `env` is a hash-table.

As an aside: it's better to use `eql` rather than `eq`.  I don't think Emacs Lisp gives any useful guarantees as to how `eq` behaves with almost any type of data (eg. I'm not sure that even interned symbols with the same name must be equal under `eq`).

Comment: I cast a down vote for the last remark about eq.  Are you aware that eq is exactly equivalent for all data types except of numeric ones?  Besides, two uninterned symbols aren't the same even if they share the same name, and hence must not be equal under eq.

Comment: @lunaryorn if you read what I wrote it says "I'm not sure that even *interned* symbols with the same name must be equal under eq". I said nothing about *uninterned* symbols. My reluctance to using `eq` is due to Common Lisp, where this is almost never a good thing to do. I don't know the implementation details of Emacs Lisp, so, it could be just a superstition on my side. Yet I'd still avoid it: you never know, maybe future Emacs Lisp will be more like Common Lisp?

Comment: With all due respect, Emacs Lisp is not Common Lisp, nor ever will be.  You might as well avoid lists because they might be removed when Emacs Lisp gets more like C.  Please remove the last paragraph from your answer; it's confusing and misleading.  Interned symbols by the way are equal under eq, simply because there's only a single obarray in Emacs Lisp.

Comment: I can and I will! I've edited the question to include a partial solution using a macro, but it's still not a full solution.

Comment: The problem with passing `env` to the custom functions is that it requires the user to add a dummy argument to their functions, as they won't necessarily know the values of `foo` `bar` and `baz`, and I feel like that's not user-friendly enough. However this has made me reconsider passing an unknown lexical environment to the user. Could be bad.

Comment: @lunaryorn Common Lisp doesn't do it arbitrary. There is a reason to it. It's a speed / memory optimization. Who knows, maybe one day Emacs Lisp will try to add more optimizations to how its memory is managed, then it might become an issue.

Comment: @rnkn Well, that's just childish. Of course it is not a restriction for what *you* can do. You certainly can do it. Whether it will work as you want it to is a different matter.

Comment: @wvxvw What kind of argument is that? There's also a reason behind Haskell's type system,too, yet Emacs Lisp is not going to become Haskell either.  Emacs Lisp is not Common Lisp, so please get over it and do not give Emacs Lisp advice based on how Common Lisp behaves.

Comment: @lunaryorn Emacs Lisp has been historically a very close relative of Common Lisp. It has many similar concerns, and it is very much different from Haskell. However, this is not just a behavior of Common Lisp. This is something that any designer of any runtime should meet at some point. This is also the reason why you must compare strings in Java using special function, why comparing pointers to literal strings in C is not a good idea etc. What I'm saying is that there is a reason for things to be the way I described, and if they aren't now, then they may be in the future.

Comment: @wvxvw Well, whatever.  Emacs Lisp is somewhat different from CL nowadays (like C++ is from C despite historical relationship), and your point about eq does simply not apply to the former, but I guess there's no point in discussing this any further.  But don't be surprised if answers about CL get down voted then.

Comment: @lunaryorn I couldn't care less.